# collision between 2 objects C#

Tags: c#, colors, unity-game-engine, kinect, collision

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CollisionExample : MonoBehaviour {

void OnCollisionEnter (Collision other){
    if(other.gameObject.name == "joint_HandRight")
    {
        this.gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.green;
    }
}

void OnCollisionStay (Collision other){
    if(other.gameObject.name == "joint_HandRight")
    {
        this.gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.green;
    }

}

void OnCollisionExit (Collision other){
    if(other.gameObject.name == "joint_HandRight")
    {
        this.gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
    }
 }
}
```

Í have a torus object named `TorusPro` and a box object with the named `joint_HandRight`.
This is the code I use on the script which is attached to my Torus object. I want its color to change when the object with the name joint_HandRight collides. It's not working. Why?

Comment: Are you sure these methods are entered? Have you tried debugging it, and seen that the code actually runs?

Comment: Perhaps you have the collider set to Trigger? Your explanation is a bit off, is join_HandRight a child of TorusPro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.**both** GameObjects must have **colliders**
2.one of the colliders must have a **non-kinematic rigidbody** attached
3.check the **collision matrix** to see if collision between their **layers** are enabled
4.**meshCollider** wont collide with meshCollider